# quantified propositional logic and predicate logic

Tags: logic

I am curious if there is a system that allows for both quantification over first-order objects and quantification over propositions, and also has inference rules that allows one to infer from a first-order formula to a formula in quantified propositional logic. More specifically, I am struggling to see how the following step could be valid in any formal system:

> **∃x (Px ∧ Φ(Px)) ⊢ ∃p(p ∧ Φ(p))**

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can check with [Stanisław Leśniewski's Protothetic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lesniewski/#Pro) and see also : J.Srzednicki and Z.Stachniak (Eds.), [Leśniewski’s Systems Protothetic](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9780792345046). The system consists in quantifying not just sentences but sentential functions or connectives : **∀f ⌈p ↔ (f(p) ↔ f(q))⌉**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see :

- Alonzo Church, [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=JDLQOMKbdScC&pg=PA295), Princeton UP (1956): **Ch.V Functional Calculi of Second Order**, page 295-on.

The calculus has porpositional variables that can be quantified and we have the axioms

> **⊢ (p)A → A[B/p]**,

where **A[B/p]** is the result of substituting formula **B** in place of propositional variable **p**, as well as the rule of inference :

> if **⊢ A**, then  **⊢ A[B/p]**.

Comment: @discretizer - You are welcome :-)